# Reliably Dismissing Webkit Notifications

Tags: javascript, html, html5-notifications

I'm successfully creating and dismissing webkit notifications like so:

```
notification = window.webkitNotifications.createNotification('foo.png', 'bar', 'baz')
notification.show()
setTimeout ->
    notification.cancel()
, 3000
```

However, the notifications aren't dismissed if the user closes or refreshes the page during those three seconds, and they stay on the desktop until manually closed.

Is there a way to reliably dismiss them under these circumstances?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [window.onunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onunload) or [window.onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) handler to clear the noifications when the page is closed.  This does not preserve the three-second delay, however, since notifications will be closed immediately when the page closes.

Another option (that *does* preserve the three-second delay) is to create the notifications from HTML pages using `createHTMLNotification(url)`.  Have the notification page close *itself* by including a script like `setTimeout(window.close, 3000)` within the notification HTML document.  In this case, obviously, you don't need a `setTimeout` call in your main page, since it is already included in the notification.

Comment: The onunload/onbeforeunload approach doesn't seem to work for me.  Can anyone confirm that this works?

Comment: The onunload/onbeforeunload approach does not work for me. I think it is because the notification handler is already destroyed before onunload/onbeforeunload.